# How to change Grails spring-security-ldap:2.0.1 plugin to use customised AuthoritiesPopulator?

Tags: grails, openldap, spring-security-ldap

I am on Grails 2.4.4, using plugins spring-security-core:2.0.0 & spring-security-ldap:2.0.1. LDAP service from OpenLdap.

The above is working, I can infer the user ROLE_ from the group user is a member of.

But we have a requirement change and we now need to infer user ROLE(s) from the nested LDAP group tree.

I checked and spring-security-ldap:2.0.1 is base on springsecurity 3.2.9, which not yet included the NestedLdapAuthoritiesPopulator, so I had went to github and grab that and few others dependencies classes, plopped them in, and modified my resources.groovy to use that, as such:

```
beans = {
ldapAuthProvider(org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider,
            ref("ldapAuthenticator"), // Use default
            ref("myLdapAuthoritiesPopulator") // Use custom
    ) {}

    myLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(com.ldap.NestedLdapAuthoritiesPopulator, ref("contextSource2"), application.config.grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase ) {}

    // Set up the manager to read LDAP
    contextSource2(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource, application.config.grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server) {       
        userDn = application.config.grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn ?:null 
        password = application.config.grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword ?:null
    }
```

But once I gave it a try, I hit an error as such:

```
Message: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
    Line | Method
->>  257 | searchForMultipleAttributeValues in com.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate$$EQx0bs0G
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    200 | performNestedSearch              in com.ldap.NestedLdapAuthoritiesPopulator
|    160 | getGroupMembershipRoles . . . .  in     ''
|    213 | getGrantedAuthorities            in com.ldap.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator$$EQx0Xl3o
|     59 | attemptAuthentication . . . . .  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter                         in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     59 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter
|   1145 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
Caused by AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
```

Anything I had missed out? Or, is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

[Edit 20180711]

I solved the above problem by adding to contextSource2 in resources.goovy:

```
    contextSource2(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource, application.config.grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server) {
        userDn = application.config.grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn ?:null
        password = application.config.grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword ?:null
        authenticationSource = ref('ldapAuthenticationSource')
        authenticationStrategy = ref('authenticationStrategy')
        anonymousReadOnly = true 
}

ldapAuthenticationSource(SimpleAuthenticationSource) {
    principal = "uid=admin,dc=myCompany,dc=com"
    credentials = "Admin123"
}
authenticationStrategy(GrailsSimpleDirContextAuthenticationStrategy) {
    userDn = "uid=admin,dc=myCompany,dc=com"
}
```

Now I can login and infer nested groups as Role, with some further problem - for a user in nested Group, it can't be found by the authorities search.

For example if I have a group hierarchy tree like this:

```
Groups -> group02 -> user01
       -> group01 (having member group02)
       -> group03 -> group04 -> user02
```

If login as user01, role inferred as ROLE_GROUP01 and ROLE_GROUP02.
But if login as user02, no role is returned at all.

I played around with config as below, but doesn't work either:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase = 'ou=Groups,dc=myCompany,dc=com'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.searchSubtree = true
```

Any help please?

If it makes a different, group01's dn is

```
cn=group01,ou=Groups,dc=myCompany,dc=com
```

and group04's dn is :

```
cn=group04,cn=group03,ou=Groups,dc=myCompany,dc=com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah nvm I figured out my last question as well - since now I am rolling my own SpringSecurityLdapTemplate class (where the search actual happends), the 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.searchSubtree' config didn't get passed down to it... 
So I just add this config directly into it somewhere before the search() call, like this:

```
SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);,
...
search(base, formattedFilter, ctls, roleMapper);
```

And it's working as expected now.